# What does “at X’s disposition” mean?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the phrase *“at their/his/her disposition”*?

For example:

> He left the apartment at the old’s man disposition.

Please explain with a few examples.

Comment: Please give more context. It seems that you actually mean "disposal", not "disposition".

Comment: Normally US English would have "disposal" rather than "disposition" in the above sentence, though I don't feel that "disposition" is necessarily incorrect.  (The meaning is somewhat dependent on the larger context, but basically means that the "old man" can make use of the apartment in some fashion.  It also implies that the "old man" can, to some degree, use his own judgement in terms of how he uses the apartment.)

Comment: Between around 1840 and 1960, *"at your disposition"* seems to have been used as a synonym for *"at your disposal"* by a minority of people writing in English. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+your+disposal%2C+at+your+disposition&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20your%20disposal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20your%20disposition%3B%2Cc0). When was this written?

Answer (score 1):

I would say "**at someone's disposal**", as in "They left a car at my disposal".

> - "at your disposal" = at your fingertips, at your service, free for use, ready for use" [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/disposal)
> - "Do you have this information at your disposal?"

user103317, I'm at your disposal for more on the subject.

Answer (score -1):

To leave something at someones disposition.

The idea behind this is that the person can dispose (make use of) the thing in anyway that person deems proper.

Just like "I like your disposition" means "I like your attitude [towards something]"

This seems to translate properly over several languages too, since there are several in which signing a letter you could say "Should you need anythin else I'm at your disposition".

Comment: Your examples, except for "I like your disposition" seem to refer to "disposal", not "disposition".

Answer (score -3):

If I do something at somebody's disposition, it means that I do that thing because some person asks me to.

Therefore, *at somebody's disposition* represents *the power to make sb do sth*.

To answer the question, if I am asked to leave the apartment at sb's disposition, it means that I am asked to do so. For example,

> The tenant was asked to leave the apartment at the owner's disposition because of unpaid rent.

On the other hand, *at sb's disposal* means completely different things. If I say I have *sth/sb at my disposal*, it means that that I can easily make use of sth/sb when the need arises. Therefore, *at sb's disposal* suggests availability of help.